# Elm sorting and [comparable]

Tags: list, sorting, elm

What sorting algorithm is used when I sort an Elm [`List`](http://library.elm-lang.org/catalog/elm-lang-Elm/0.12.3/List)?

```
> sort [1,3,5,6]
[1,3,5,6] : [comparable]
```

What is the `[comparable]` type and how to I get back a `number`?

```
> [1,2]:: (sort [3,2,1])
[1 of 1] Compiling Repl                ( repl-temp-000.elm )
Type error on line 4, column 3 to 24:
        [1,2] :: (sort [3,2,1])

   Expected Type: [number]
     Actual Type: comparable
```

This may be a good time to understand how `List` is implemented in Elm, but I am not trying to ask anything too deep right now.  Just get it up and running.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sort converts the list to a javascript array and then calls sort on that and then converts the result back into an elm list. This means that the sort itself is whatever implementation the browser is using (definitely an order size * log(size) algorithm).

Source for sort in elm: https://github.com/elm-lang/Elm/blob/20ccc834c1a597d1ef356c14073670b62f90d875/libraries/Native/List.js#L267-L269

The `comparable` type is interesting but does encompass number. The issue with your code is you are using `(::)` (pronounce cons) rather than `(++)` pronounced append. You want to do:

```
sorted = [1,2] ++ (sort [6,5,4,3])
```

Example: http://share-elm.com/sprout/53dd978ce4b07afa6f983b7d

Hope this helps!